# Stuck at TIME COMPLEXITY , Need a less complex solution for generating polygons from given list of edge length

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, combinations

I have written a code for counting the number of polygons which can be created from the given sticks (i.e: lengths).

> For sticks = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], the output should be
>   polygonsCount(sticks) = 13.
>
> Here are all the polygons that can be obtained from sticks with
>   lengths 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6:
>
> ```
> (2, 3, 4);
> (3, 4, 5);
> (2, 4, 5);
> (2, 5, 6);
> (3, 4, 6);
> (3, 5, 6);
> (4, 5, 6);
> (2, 3, 4, 5);
> (2, 3, 4, 6);
> (2, 3, 5, 6);
> (2, 4, 5, 6);
> (3, 4, 5, 6);
> (2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
> ```

The program is working fine but, because of time complexity it is crossing time limit for greater lists.

First I generated a power-set of the given lists of sticks. I tried to avoid [ ] to all [ x , x ] -- 2 element subsets, but failed, also, I do not think it will reduce the time complexity.
Then I check for possible polygons. But I am getting Time limit. Here is the code:

```
def powersetGenerator(sticks,blankSet):
    if sticks ==[]:
        yield blankSet
    else:
        for item in powersetGenerator(sticks[1:],blankSet+[sticks[0]]):
            yield item
        for item in powersetGenerator(sticks[1:],blankSet):
            yield item

def possiblePolygons(array):
    sumOfAll = sum(array)
    longestSide = max(array)
    return longestSide < sumOfAll - longestSide

def polygonsCount(sticks):
    powerset = list(powersetGenerator(sticks,[]))
    count = 0
    for index in range(len(powerset)):
        if len(powerset[index])>=3 and possiblePolygons(powerset[index]) == 1:
            count=(count+1)%((10**9) + 7)
    return count
```

Comment: Calculating powerset is O(2**n). You should do it without powerset.

Comment: **How?** I have no idea!

Comment: @Ibrahim Are all stick length different like in your example? If yes, that would made the problem easier.

Comment: @VPfB not necessarily, One test case is like this: 
**[88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88]**

Comment: @Ibrahim OK, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use *itertools.combinations()* from the Python standard library to generate the polygons:

```
def polygonGenerator(sticks):
    for r in range(3, len(sticks)+1):
        polygons = itertools.combinations(sticks, r)
        # for lexicographical order & pretty printing
        polygons = list(set(polygons))
        polygons.sort()
        #
        for polygon in polygons:
            yield polygon
```

For Python3 without lexicographical ordering *polygonGenerator()* can be refactored to:

```
def polygonGenerator(sticks):
    for r in range(3, len(sticks)+1):
        yield from set(itertools.combinations(sticks, r))
```

Comment: This wont going to solve the time complexity issue. the key to a proper solution might be in computing the count without constructing the polygons.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same solution with the same complexity but with lots of optimisations in order to prevent repeated operations.

```
# updated version
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(None)
def s_s_l(items):
    """return a list of items [subset, sum, length]"""
    if not items:
        return [[[], 0, 0]] 
    first, *rest = items    # python3 syntax
    ss1 = s_s_l(tuple(rest))
    ss2 = [[[first]+ss[0], first+ss[1], 1+ss[2]] for ss in ss1]
    return ss1 + ss2 

def polygons(sticks):
    """yield polygons"""
    sticks = sorted(sticks, reverse=True)
    prev_longest = None
    for i in range(len(sticks)-2):
        longest = sticks[i]
        if longest == prev_longest:
            continue
        prev_longest = longest
        for subset, nsum, nlen in s_s_l(tuple(sticks[i+1:])):
            if nsum > longest and nlen >= 2:
                yield([longest] + subset)

def count_pg(sticks):
    """count unique polygons"""
    solutions = {tuple(pg) for pg in polygons(sticks)}
    return len(solutions)

print(count_pg([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
print(count_pg([88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88]))
```

---

I might be wrong, but the key to a proper solution might be in computing the count without constructing the polygons. Somebody with a better mathematical foundation might know the answer.

Comment: This wont going to solve the time complexity issue. **the key to a proper solution might be in computing the count without constructing the polygons. Somebody with a better mathematical foundation might know the answer.**

Comment: @Ibrahim I do not know about different approach and nobody has shown it so far. Maybe it does not exist, I don't know. So I posted a code with many optimisations. Better than nothing.